# DataError: (psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation) value too long for type character varying(256)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, amazon-redshift, pandas-to-sql

I am trying to write a Python data frame to redshift. I wrote this code -

```
df.to_sql(sheetname, con=conn,if_exists='replace',chunksize=250, index=False)  
conn.autocommit = True
```

I am getting below error:

```
DataError: (psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation) value too long for type character varying(256)
```

I have 300+ columns and 1080 rows.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages looks to be from Redshift and is indicating that one of the values you are attempting to insert into the table is too large for the definition of that column.

> "value too long for type character varying(256)"

The column is defined to be VARCHAR(256) but the value being inserted is larger than this.  You should be able to inspect the length of the strings you are inserting (in your python code) to find the offending value(s).  Alternatively you can look at the statement history in Redshift to find the offending command.

One thing to note is that Redshift uses UTF-8 to encode data and for some characters it needs to use a multi-byte encoding.  These encodings can take more than one byte to represent certain characters.  The defined length of the column is in bytes, not characters, so a string that has 250 characters can take more than 256 bytes to represent it if there are more than a handful of multi-byte characters in the string.  If you are on the hairy edge of not fitting in the defined column length you may want to check your string lengths in bytes with a multi-byte UTF-8 encoding.